# How to show all layers in the mapbox once button is unclicked?

Tags: javascript, html, css, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I have around 7-9 layers in my mapbox. The variable "toggleableLayerIds" have all the layer names.
I have created a functionality that when a button is clicked only that specific layer in shows on the map.
But when I un-click the button i should see all the layers appear in the map.
How do I achieve this

Below attached is my code snippet:

```
mapboxgl.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1IjoibXBhbmRhIiwiYSI6ImNrZXUxMTlvYTI4dWYydXQ1c29xamthOHkifQ.DMoQHp6Js8MR-FPW5MpV9g';
        var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
            container: 'map',
            style: 'mapbox://styles/mpanda/ckgsz2his0l7c19rwesmr8amr'
        }); 

   
map.on('load', function () {
            //Declaring all Layers
            var toggleableLayerIds = ['Shops', 'Church', 'Tourist Spots', 'Bakery', 'Bars and Pubs', 'Restaurants', 'Cafes','Tram Stops'];
        //Button
        //#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        for (var i = 0; i < toggleableLayerIds.length; i++) {
            var id = toggleableLayerIds[i];

            var link = document.createElement('a');
            link.href = '#';
            link.className = 'active';
            link.textContent = id;

            var layers = document.getElementById('button');
            layers.appendChild(link);


            link.onclick = function (e) {
                var clickedLayer = this.textContent;
                e.preventDefault();
                e.stopPropagation();

                for (var j = 0; j < toggleableLayerIds.length; j++) {
                    if (clickedLayer == toggleableLayerIds[j]) {
                        layers.children[j].className = 'active';
                        map.setLayoutProperty(toggleableLayerIds[j], 'visibility', 'visible');
                    }
                    else {
                        layers.children[j].className = '';
                        map.setLayoutProperty(toggleableLayerIds[j], 'visibility', 'none');
                    }
                }
            };
        }
        } );//load
```

Here is my css as well

```
#button {
  background: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  width: 120px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
  font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif;
}
#button a {
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #404040;
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
  text-align: center;
}
#button a:last-child {
  border: none;
}
#button a:hover {
  background-color: #f8f8f8;
  color: #404040;
}
#button a.active {
  background-color: #3887be;
  color: #ffffff;
}
#button a.active:hover {
  background: #3074a4;
}
```

Comment: Hey, toggling layer visibility is the correct way to hide/unhide layers. Attaching couple of link's which could help you in achieving your motives https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/filter-markers/  and https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/toggle-interaction-handlers/ and https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/toggle-layers/